# Outlook Add-In Built using Angular showing blank screen on Windows Outlook App pre 1903 build

Tags: angular, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, polyfills

We are developing an Outlook add-in using angular. The add-in works on IE11, Edge, Chrome and Safari, but on Windows Outlook desktop app versions (< 1903) which use IE11, it shows an empty screen. Here is my pollyfills file:

```js
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js'; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'intersection-observer';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

I have also added the

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`

in index.html.

These two solutions I could find in google but they dont work.

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 25670 in mydomain.com/polyfills- 
es5.39e9f85b88cc5eac0d73.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.getPrototypeOf: 'this' is not an Object
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 203956 in mydomain.com/polyfills- 
es5.39e9f85b88cc5eac0d73.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 46550 in mydomain.com/polyfills- 
es5.39e9f85b88cc5eac0d73.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.freeze: argument is not an Object
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 1586 in mydomain.com/polyfills- 
es5.39e9f85b88cc5eac0d73.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.seal: argument is not an Object
```

Any assistance on the same would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS depends on a few window.history APIs, these APIs are not supported by the Desktop IE runtime. So when using AngularJS you must nullify the window.history APIs by adding `<script>window.history.replaceState=null;window.history.pushState=null;</script>` to your index.html page. Also, it's always good to check for pollyfill issues when using IE webview.